# installing rails rake conflicts with usr/bin/rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After using command "$ sudo gem install rails", an error occurred saying "rake's executable "rake" conflicts with /usr/bin/rake". I have searched errors regarding this install and can't find any solutions. Please Help!

Answer (score 1):

All I can recommend is try to setup your environment for development or production on a non-sudo-user base.

A great tool I prefer and use for managing multiple rubies and gems is [rvm](https://rvm.io/)

The best place for up-to-date-how-to-start-with-rails is the [RailsApps Project](http://railsapps.github.io/installing-rails.html)

Comment: Good alternatives are [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) and [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby)